gtk2 compile error: DSO missing from command line
This is a new question resulting from a recent question of mine: compiling error gtk2 source with gtk3: ‘GtkStyle’ {aka ‘struct _GtkStyle’} has no member named ‘font’
make process of compiling emelfm, a gtk2 source program, in a current Gentoo linux gtk3 generated all .0 files (35) after making the following changes:
Makefile.common - replacing "gtk-config" and "glib-config" words with "pkg-config":
PREFIX = /usr/local
BIN_DIR = $(PREFIX)/bin
LOCALEDIR = $(PREFIX)/share/locale
PLUGINS_DIR = $(PREFIX)/share/emelfm/plugins
DOC_DIR = $(PREFIX)/share/emelfm/docs

NLS = -DENABLE_NLS
GTK_INCLUDE = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`
GTK_LIB = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
GLIB_LIB = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

CC = gcc -O2 -Wall

5 out of 35 .c files: "->" style statements produced errors, but "_get_active" style allowed compiling process to continue. These are the actual changes in those 5 .c files:
window.c
line 257    style->font = app.output_font;
            style_get_active (app.output_font);

utils.c
line 275    system_ops[i].func(NULL);
            i;
line 289    interface_ops[i].func(NULL);
            i;

view_dialog.c
line 83     scrollbar = gtk_vscrollbar_new(GTK_TEXT(text_area)->vadj);
            scrollbar_get_active (gtk_vscrollbar_new(GTK_TEXT(text_area)));

fileview.c
line 702    style->font = font;
            style_get_active (gdk_font_load);

command_panel.c
line 450    style->font = app.output_font;
            style_get_active (app.output_font);
line 382    adj = GTK_TEXT(app.output_text)->vadj;
            adj_get_active (GTK_TEXT(app.output_text));
line 393    adj = GTK_TEXT(app.output_text)->vadj;
            adj_get_active (GTK_TEXT(app.output_text));

However, the make process stops with DSO error:
gcc -O2 -Wall .... -o emelfm `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: plugins.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g_module_error'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:22: emelfm] Error 1


The four dots represent list of 35 .o files
I realize I did not completely rewrite the .c files according to gte3 rules, but it looked like gtk3 was smart enough (AI?) to understand most statements with warnings, and I was happy to have the .o files done. Is there a similar shortcut, easy way to fix the linking problem?
Apparently libgmodule-2.0.so.0 is not in the path of something even though that file is in /usr/lib64.
Otherwise I'll drop this challenge and continue to use xfe file manager. emelfm was on my older desktop, starting with Fedora-3.

This has previously been answered
Linking error: DSO missing from command line

GTK_LIB = pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0

You're now using pkg-config to find the options needed for compiling and linking. But you're still looking for GTK 2 and not for GTK 3. The correct setting is
GTK_LIB = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

But this alone won't help. Migration to GTK3 is not possible without changes to the C Code.
Update:
To help you get started you might want to consult the GTK 3 introduction at https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/compiling.html
Maybe you could start with a small program just to make sure that you have every dependencies installed. And then it would make sense to work through the migration docs in the GTK 3 Site.
Are you aware of emelfm2?

Thx. I need more quidance on the DSO answer. "pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0" works, but "pkg-config --libs gmodule" complains about package gmodule not found - yet libgmodule-2.0.so is in my /usr/lib64 directory juast as libgtk-3.so is there. I'm not a coder, just linux enthusiast. Yes, I tried emelfm2 source as well and it failed to compile even though it is gtk3 compatible(?).   OK I can just give up because I jave an old, working executable emelfm copied from an old Fedora-3 machine.
